# How can I change the binary file link to something else

Tags: linux, symlink

I have two questions and they are linked. I execute the command like this:

`python` on the shell and it opens the shell.

Now I want

1. To which file it is linked. I mean when I run `python` then what is the path of file it opens like `/usr/bin/python` or what?
2. The other questions is I want to change that link to some other location so that when I run `python` then it opens `/usr/bal/bla/python2.7`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command run when you type `python` is determined primarily by the setting of your `$PATH`.  The first executable file called `python` that is found in a directory listed on your `$PATH` will be the one executed.  There is no 'link' per se.  The `which` command will tell you what the shell executes when you type `python`.

If you want `python` to open a different program, there are a number of ways to do it.  If you have `$HOME/bin` on your `$PATH` ahead of `/usr/bin`, then you can create a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/bal/bla/python2.7 $HOME/bin/python
```

This will now be executed instead of `/usr/bin/python`.  Alternatively, you can create an alias:

```
alias python=/usr/bal/bla/python2.7
```

Alternatively again, if `/usr/bal/bla` contains other useful programs, you could add `/usr/bal/bla` to your `$PATH` ahead of `/usr/bin`.

There are other mechanisms too, but one of these is likely to be the one you use.  I'd most probably use the symlink in `$HOME/bin`.